# How to create a multiple choice question in oTree?

Tags: python, multiple-choice, otree

I was wondering if it is possible to have a multiple choice question in otree. Something like radio button but that lets you choose more than one thing. 
What I'm thinking of is something like:

Question: The following list of statements contains three correct statements and three false statements. Please select the three **correct** statements:

- Statement 1
- Statement 2
- Statement 3
- Statement 4
- Statement 5
- Statement 6

Comment: yes, it does. See here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/otree/CLmiH595UDM/QnPSQyf-BAAJ
- it's a link to official oTree group forum where this has been discussed. In fact it is just a simple django Multiple choice select widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `otree_models.models.MultipleChoiceFormField` for this purpose, as sketched out in the following:

In `models.py`:

```
from otree.api import BasePlayer
from otree_tools.models import fields as tool_models

class Player(BasePlayer):

    correct_statements = tool_models.MultipleChoiceModelField(label="Please select the three correct statements",
                                                              min_choices=3, max_choices=3)
```

In `pages.py`:

```
from ._bultin import Page

class ExamplePage(Page):

    form_model = "player"
    form_fields = ["correct_statements"]

    def correct_statements_choices(self):
         """Return the list of statements to choose from."""
         return ["Statement 1", "Statement 2", "Statement 3",
                 "Statement 4", "Statement 5", "Statement 6"]
```

In `ExamplePage.html`, simply include the form field:

```
{% extends "global/Page.html" %}
{% load otree %}

{% block content %}
The following list of statements contains three correct statements and three false statements. 

{% formfield player.correct_statements %}

{% next_button %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where does "otree_tools" come from? It's not available in my otree installation.

Comment: This is a [separate library](https://github.com/chapkovski/otree_tools) but I don't think it's compatible with recent versions of oTree.